# Calculating Digital Root, is there a better way?

Tags: java, math

This is how i calculated the digital root of an integer.

---

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Problem7 extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        println("This program calculates the digital root of an interger.");

        int num = readInt("Enter the number: ");
        int sum = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (num > 0)
            {
                int dsum = num % 10;
                num /= 10;
                sum += dsum;
            }
            else if (sum > 9)
            {
                int dsum = sum % 10;
                sum /= 10;
                sum += dsum;

            } else if (sum <= 9 ) break;
        }
        println("Digital Root is: " + sum);
    }
```

---

The program works fine.

Is there a better/shorter way of calculating the digital root of a number. ?

---

EDIT/ADDED : Here is the implementation of the above problem by using [Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58657/tyler)'s answer, it works as well:

---

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Problem7 extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        println("This program calculates the digital root of an interger.");

        int num = readInt("Enter the number: ");
        println("Digital Root of " + num + " is: " + (1 + (num - 1) % 9));
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int number;
   scanf("%d", &number);

   printf("The digital root of %d is %d.", number, (1 + (number - 1) % 9));
}
```

Had I not been able to find Ramans' formula this is how I would write this program...:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int number = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
            number += (c - '0');
    }
    if (number <= 9)
    {
        printf("The digital root is %d\n", number);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d", number);
    }

}
```

After compiling, to run this, basically you just chain these together. I believe four is the most you could possibly need for an integer.

```
$ echo 829382938 | ./digitalroot | ./digitalroot | ./digitalroot | ./digitalroot
```

Comment: This formula resides at the bottom of the page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

It's quite brilliant.

Comment: @Ibn

Oops! Didn't see that.

In this case, Ramans' formula isn't really an algorithm in the same way the Pythatgorean theorum isn't really an algorithm. Ramans' formula was most likely derived via pure math.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not like your loop, which is essentially two loops (first going over the original digits, then going over the digits of sum) mashed into one. How about a sprinkling of recursion:

```
private int sumDigits(int in){
   if (i>10)
      return in%10 + sumDigits(in/10);
    return in;
}

private int digitalRoot(int in){
    assert (in > 0) ;
    while (in > 9)  in=sumDigits(in);
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I am at the same point in the class, no recursion or any moderately advanced ideas (I'm a super beginner).  I used

```
public void run() {
    println("This program finds the digital root of an integer.");
    int n = readInt("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int dsum = 0;
        while (n>0) {
            dsum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            if ((n==0) && (dsum>9)) {
                n = dsum;
                dsum = 0;
            }   
        }
    println("The digital root of the integer is " + dsum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is amazing. It pretty much spoon fed me the follow solution:

```
int getDigitalRoot(int n, int base){
      return (1+(n-1)%base); }

int getDigitalRoot(int n){
      return (1+(n-1)%9); }
```

This is a O(1) solution, no loops, or recursion necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the input in as a String instead. This way, you can simply loop through the String and use Integer.parseInt() to grab each number and add them. You can convert that number again to a String and loop through the code to obtain your digital root.

```
public void run()
{
    println("This program calculates the digital root of an interger.");

    String num = readLine("Enter the number: ");
    int sum = 10;
    while (num > 9) {
      for (int x = 0; x < num.length(); x++) {
         sum = Integer.parseInt(num.charAt(x));
      }
      num = Integer.toString(sum);
   }
   println("Digital Root is: " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)


{
int n;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the no. of which you want to find the digital root");
n=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(n%9);
}
```

Comment: can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: This doesn't work for multiples of 9, e.g. 18 % 9 = 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest solution I have found that works for all use cases.

```
public int digRoot(int num) {
        num = 1015; {
        return (1+(num-1)%9);
        }
}
```

ref: https://dgeekspot.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/digital-root-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in C# and there is kinda stuff that is useless but I hope that will help you.

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

  public static int DigitalRoot(long n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    if (n <= 10) return n == 10 ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(n);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        sum += (n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum > 9 ? DigitalRoot(sum) : Convert.ToInt32(sum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://csgsd.com/mathematics/digital-root-calculator
Digital Root Calculator

```
 <div class="bloks">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="number" class="form-label">Enter a number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" required>
        <div id="numberHelp" class="form-text">Please enter a positive integer.</div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="calculateDigitalRoot()" class="axil-button button-rounded btn-primary" style="margin-top:40px;">Calculate Digital Root</button>
    <div id="result" class="mt-3" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function calculateDigitalRoot() {
        var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0) {
            document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Please enter a valid positive integer.</div>';
            return;
        }
        
        var sum = num;
        var steps = [];
        while (sum > 9) {
            var digits = sum.toString().split('');
            var stepExplanation = digits.join(' + ') + ' = ' + digits.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0);
            steps.push(stepExplanation);
            sum = digits.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr), 0);
        }
        
        var resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';
        resultMessage += 'Digital Root of ' + num + ' is: ' + sum + '.<br>';
        if (steps.length > 0) {
            resultMessage += 'Steps:<br>' + steps.join('<br>') + '.';
        }
        resultMessage += '</div>';
        
        document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultMessage;
    }
</script>
```