# Finding the Digital Root in (Functional) JavaScript - Returning very strange values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I've been playing around with functional programming and some of the challenges set on websites like Codewars (in JavaScript). One challenge I undertook was to find the digital root of an input integer `n` (i.e. the sum of each of `n`'s individual digits). I'd really like some help fixing it, but by using the functional paradigm, because I've already done this task by other means with OOP techniques. The code used follows:

```
const digitalRoot = n => {
  let arr = n.toString().split('').map(x => parseInt(x, 10)), sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
};
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work in most cases. It returns as follows, for example:

```
digitalRoot(15); //returns 15 instead of 6
digitalRoot(108); //returns 108 instead of 9
digitalRoot(20); //returns 20 instead of 2
```

However, in some instances it does work:

```
digitalRoot(16); //returns 7 as expected
digitalRoot(0); //returns 0 as expected
```

Could anyone explain to me what the issue with this is and how I might go about fixing it? I'm not sure if it's continuing to be treated as a string despite `parseInt` being used or what. Please let me know if converting to a string and then an array etc. are bad practice, and/or the wrong approach. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: All your examples give the correct result for me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: A `for` loop isn't really functional programming. Either recursion or `.reduce()` would be more functional.

Comment: It could perhaps be an issue with the test environment used on the website. I'll quickly chuck it into JSBin and see if it still does this.

Comment: You are all correct. The issue is with the test environment as running these tests independently by hand elsewhere returns the correct values. However, I would be really interested @Barmar if you could show how you would do this either with recursion and/or .reduce(). Thanks!

Comment: @dhalbat solve the challenge, then you can have a look at the other solutions ;)

Comment: The challenge is clearly broken seeing as this code works anywhere else but in the test environment! I've cleared it using another method though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the numbers together with reduce instead of using map, especially so if you're aiming to use "functional" javascript:

```js
const rootNum = n =>
  n.toString().split('').reduce((all, current)=>parseInt(current) + all, 0);

console.log(rootNum(1));
console.log(rootNum(20));
console.log(rootNum(440));
console.log(rootNum(1012340));
console.log(rootNum(1021394812));
```

Comment: The point of coding challenges is for him to figure this out himself. You're not helping him learn by just doing it for him.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, where do you see that in the rules? Learning by example is easier than shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution can be a recursive method. As long as `n` is not 0, get the last digit using the [remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()), and remove it from the number by dividing by 10, and rounding the results down.

```js
const digitalRoot = n => 
  n && n % 10 + digitalRoot(Math.floor(n / 10));
  
console.log(digitalRoot(15));
console.log(digitalRoot(108));
console.log(digitalRoot(20));
console.log(digitalRoot(16));
console.log(digitalRoot(0));
```

Comment: The question was "how can I fix it?" And "is that a bad practice?", also this is a coding challenge.

Comment: Since his code works fine, and he did ask for a functional solution, I've added one.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the use of the ternary operator ? here. Where is the comparison with 0 done? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dhalbat - If `n` is 0, it's evaluated to false, and `0` is returned. I've replaced it with short-circuit, as long as the number is not 0, the recursion will continue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was interested, I came across a mathematical formula for this in the [Java section of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057072/calculating-digital-root-is-there-a-better-way/46626307#46626307), which would eliminate the need for any sort of looping or recursion, or calling other functions at all.

The resulting code is:

```
const digitalRoot = n => 1 + (n - 1) % 9;
```

This relies on the mathematical properties of numbers, as discussed [here](https://dgeekspot.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/digital-root-algorithm/).